# Angular $http method called in function only works once

Tags: ajax, angularjs

I have this function in an angular service that I want to call multiple times throughout my app.

Version 1

```
getNearbyRestaurants: function(){

    $http.get(url)
        .success(function(data){
            console.log("works here")
            // do stuff with the data
        }) 
        .error(function(){
            console.log("got an error");
            // do stuff with the error
        });


}
```

Version 2

```
getNearbyRestaurants: function(lat, lng){

    var latLng = "ll=" + lat + "," + lng

    return $http.get(url + latLng)
}
```

The first time I call this function all is well, but any subsequent calls won't do anything. I make it into the function just fine, but the $http service doesn't actually make a call to the url and neither the success nor the error functions get called. I'm not entirely sure what's wrong here. It should work everytime. Am I missing some basic understanding of the $http service?

Comment: Why don't you post the not simplified version?

Comment: Where is URL defined?

Comment: elsewhere in the service. it's just a simple call to foursquare's api. https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?client_id=myId&client_secret=mySecret&v=20130815&ll=40.7,-74&query=food

Comment: So URL is a global variable, and there aren't any other places where it's redefined? Also, what specifically does "url" contain?

Comment: could you prepare fiddle or plunkr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I resolved this issue. What was happening was I was calling the function from outside of Angular (from the google maps event callback). So all I needed to do was wrap the function call in $rootScope.$apply and everything worked perfect.